# Allow SSH direct Root user login to particular IP addresses

Tags: ssh, centos, sshd

I have configured ssh login disable direct root user, configuration are,

**/etc/ssh/sshd_config**

```
  Port  1845
  PermitRootLogin no
  AllowUsers SKBFSXDWA
```

I would like to direct root login to specific IP address how to configure in ssh, for example

ssh -p 1845 root@192.168.0.50

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to your query is: add one of the follwoing lines to your */etc/sshd/sshd_config* file,

```
         AllowUsers root@192.168.0.1
         AllowUsers root@192.168.0.?
```

The first line allows root to login from a single IP address, the second one from the whole subnet 192.168.0.0/24. Now restart your ssh daemon, and you are good to go.

Even if allowed from a very restricted set of IP addresses, root logins are security  hazards. You may get tens, hundreds of break-in attempts daily. If I were you, I would **not** allow root login, period. At any rate, simple advice to strengthen your system:

1. Use a non-default port, something like 55772, instead of port 22.
2. Use cryptographic keys, not passwords, for authentication. This is the single most important piece of advice.
3. Use *fail2ban* to ban IP addresses that try several unsuccessful logins within a short period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of permitting root login, try this instead:

Create a standard user, or use one that exists. You now have 2 choices

1. `su`
2. `sudo`

For choice 1, login to the user account you just created, and run `su`. This will allow you to type the root password, and gain root. Beware you need to execute `exit` then `logout` to logout from root, then disconnect.

For choice 2, you again, have two choices:

1. `sudo adduser <username> sudo`
2. `sudo usermod -a -G sudo <username>`

The first is to create a user and add it to the sudoers group. The second is to mod a existing user, and add them to the sudoers group. Once done with either of the two above, you may login as the user, and execute `sudo` to start something as root, or `sudo -s` to elevate yourself to root. With elevation you will need to use `exit` then `logout` to logout of SSH